# Multiple values for a powershell alais

Tags: powershell, alias

I want to create an alias that will display my home directory and all of it's sub-directories.

The alias that I can create is-
**new-alias -name myd -value get-childitem**

But I need to display both the home directory and sub directories using one command.  Can I assign multiple values for an alias?

Answer (score 3):

You should create a function and do that:

```
function  myd {Get-ChildItem -Recurse }
```

Then alias that if you wish:

```
New-Alias -Name myname -Value myd
```

You can directly call the "myd" also.

Comment: See also `Set-Alias` : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/set-alias?view=powershell-5.1

Comment: @WillWebb: I know it . But why you want to set it with an existing one ?

Comment: "By default, aliases are not saved between Windows PowerShell sessions: each time you restart Windows PowerShell you’ll need to recreate the alias." - By creating a profile you can then add Set-Alias to ensure you can use your new alias on each PowerShell instance with your profile.

Comment: So what about the function? That also you have to compile everytime. You should not alter the profiler script. rather than create a startup script

Comment: The answer is: this should be something he puts into his `$Profile`.  Additionally, your function should read `Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $env:UserProfile -Recurse`

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1: Right :)